# How to access the "Shared with me" root list with Google Drive SDK?

Tags: google-drive-api

In the Google Drive SDK documentation, I can't figure out how to access the *root* list of files/folders shared with me by others, any idea?

I tried to search for files not owned by me, meaning query files/list with the following parameter:

```
"q=not 'me' in owners"
```

But that returns all the files owned by others, not only the "root list" of those files.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apparently, there is a new [search parameter](https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters?hl=en), called `sharedWithMe`. Setting the Q to "sharedWithMe" is enough to receive the parent folders and files that were shared with the user. It can be combined with other parameters too - for example "sharedWithMe and trashed=false".

You have probably already found about it, but it might be useful to have an answer of this question.

Comment: Yes indeed, but unfortunately this search parameter doesn't allow you to get *ONLY* the *ROOT* elements of this hierarchy.

Comment: What do you mean? When a user shares with me Folder1 that has subfolders and files inside, I can get only Folder1 using "sharedWithMe". Any files and folders that have been explicitly shared through the menus will be listed in the response. Any files and folders that are inside a shared folder, won't be listed in the response.
Or do you need the shared items that are in the sharing user's root?

Comment: I'm not sure if they changed something or if I haven't sleep enough these days but it's indeed working now. :) Thanks Stan!

Comment: If somebody shares you just a file then that file is "in Google Docs root". At least old Google Docs API was showing that these objects have root as parent.

Comment: OK Sounds to me like they give you the first level of the files shared with you and folders. So it will return all lowest level folders, then also the files that are directly shared. Otherwise it expects you to use `children()` to get the rest of the files.

Comment: Hi @stan0 ,@RobertGrezan! I have a problem with combined parameters. When I do with only 'sharedWithMe' option I get response { "id": "somefolderid", "name": "Name"}. And when I do " 'somefolderid' in parents" it returns all files and folders from somefolderid folder. But when I do " 'somefolderid' in parents and sharedWithMe" it returns empty collection. Does anybody could explain where is mistake?

Comment: @Anton what are you trying to achieve with that query? It looks strange

Comment: @stan0 
I'm trying to get all shared-with-me files/folders which has somefolderId as parent.

Answer (score -4):

Something more like:

"q=not 'me' in owners and 'root' in parents"

Comment: That's the first thing I tried but shared files doesn't inherit from the 'root' parent; They haven't any parent so this isn't working.

Comment: I have the same problem - couldnt find a solution so far :(

Comment: It looks like Google use the old Google Document API to do that.