# Retrieving top level files in shared with me from google drive v3 java api

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I want to query only the top level files from a google drive using java api (v3). **(By top level, I mean I don't want to go recursively into folders)**

I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12473726/how-to-access-the-shared-with-me-root-list-with-google-drive-sdk#comment75177950_12473726), but it does not seems to have a proper solution(even though it has a accepted solution).

I have tried couple of things :

1) I tried setting the **Query**

```
 // this gives the shared files, but gives all files, not just the top files
 Files.List request = drive.files().list().setQ("sharedWithMe = true");
```

2) I read somewhere that top level files in **shared with me** does not have any parent, So I tried to get files  which does not have any parent

Similar to **'root' in parents** for My Drive files, I tried couple of queries :

```
  drive.files().list().setQ("sharedWithMe = true and null in parents");

  drive.files().list().setQ("sharedWithMe = true and parents = null");
```

but they does not seem to work.

3) I tried getting all the files and then tried to select files only which has does not have parent.

```
   Files.List request = drive.files().list()
    .setQ("sharedWithMe = true)
    .setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name, parents)");
```

even after including **parents** in output fields, **File.getParents()** gives *NULL*(even for files which have parent).

**Question** :

Is there a way we can get parents information for each file with **Files.list()**?

Is there a way to get files at top level of shared with me folder?(by adding some query along with **sharedWithMe = true**)

Comment: Only solution that I can think of is to use alias `root` to refer to the root folder anywhere a file ID is provided. See [Work with Folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/folder) and this related [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483808/google-drive-api-v3-getting-root-folder-id-in-java) for more information.

Comment: @Teyam I think the SO post gives the id of `My drive` root, isn't it? If I know a file id in *Shared with me*, is there a way find its root?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @casolorz No, I didn't find any way to do this. But the last time I looked at this was in June 2017, I am not sure if it changed after that.

Comment: From looking around it seems like asking for shared with me folders will lead to getting only the root folders that were shared with you. You could then filter those that have parents if you don't want to show them there as well.

Answer (score 0):

I could get the list of only **the root level files shared with me**, using the following code in Google Drive API V3.

First get both the files and folders of **shared with me** using the below code

```
FileList sharedWithMeResult = drive.files().list().setQ("sharedWithMe=true").execute();
```

To filter out the folders, you can do

```
List<com.google.api.services.drive.model.File> sharedWithMeFiles = sharedWithMeResult.getFiles();

for (com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file : sharedWithMeFiles) 
{
    if(file.getMimeType().contains("vnd.google-apps.folder"))
        continue;
    else
       System.out.println("Shared File Name = " + file.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking for this.

The only solution I found was to get a random file, and follow its ancestors until getting a folder with null parent. That should be the top folder. But this process involves several google api calls. And I don't know if it is guaranteed to always work.

It is here: https://github.com/idnael/2023_android_TestGoogleDrive